# PHP Composer Autoload not loading classes

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

Somehow I have problems with the composer autoloader. I am using Propel as ORM framework. My folder structure looks the following:

```
src/BestFreeSites/App
- /Map
- /Base
src/BestFreeSites/Auth
src/BestFreeSites/Framework
```

I want to include all files using composer autoload. My composer.json file looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
    "src/BestFreeSites/App/",
    "src/BestFreeSites/App/Base/",
    "src/BestFreeSites/App/Map/",
    "src/BestFreeSites/Auth/",
    "src/BestFreeSites/Framework/"
]
}
```

The classes in the first three folders are accessible, but not the classes in Auth and Framework (created by me).
I've also set the correct namespaces. Let's take AuthController.php (in folder Auth) as an example:

```
namespace BestFreeSites\Auth;

public class AuthController
{

    public function register($args)
    {
        return $args;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to include the file with 'use', like this:

```
use \BestFreeSites\App\SiteQuery;
use \BestFreeSites\App\UserQuery;
use \BestFreeSites\App\RatingQuery;
use \BestFreeSites\Auth\AuthController as Auth;
use \BestFreeSites\Framework\Abstract;
```

Only the last two imports are not working.
I have already dumped my autoload and reloaded it (*composer dump-autoload*)

Could anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance :)

Kind regards,
David

Comment: when loading your classes , what's the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is your real`\BestFreeSites\Auth\AuthController` class located? Can you provide script level directory hierarchy?

And did you require your `vendor/autoload.php` file correctly?

Or if you just want to set your psr4 autoloader, then follow the following code for your `composer.json` file.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "BestFreeSites\\": "src/BestFreeSites"
        }
    }
}
```

```
//use your AuthController class
$autoController = new \BestFreeSites\Auth\AuthController();
```

It's pretty straightforward. I guess, it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That helped! However, for another class (which I now included the same way I'm getting the same error and can't find the reason:

    `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Abstract' (T_ABSTRACT), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in C:\Entwicklung\Apps\propelBackend\src\routing\public.php on line 29`

Line 29 is: 
`$abstr = new \BestFreeSites\Framework\Abstract();` Sorry, could you please point me in the right direction? I'm still getting used to the namepsaces in PHP :D

Comment: You cannot name a class `Abstract`, which you did by naming it `BestFreeSites\...\Abstract` and using it as `Abstract`. "abstract" is a PHP keyword for abstract classes.

Comment: Damn - should have thought about that earlier. Thanks a lot for your help :)